# Update ViewBag Data on MVC Razor View page using JSON Data JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to update the ViewBag on MVC Razor view page using JSON data. But it is not updating the ViewBag or Div. When I am looking the alert on my success, it is showing the updated values but inside the page, it is not changing the value. Initially when page is loading, it is showing the values.

My JQuery code is -

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#ddl2').change(function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var str_test = $("#v_ddl2 :selected").text();           
            var data1 = {str_test: str_test }; 
            var url = '@Url.Action("ddl_2")?id=' + id;

            $.post(url, data1, function (data)
            {
                $('#nav_div').html(data);
                alert(JSON.stringify(data)); // ALERT showing the updated data
            });

        });
    });
```

Controller -

```
public JsonResult ddl_2(string str_test)
    {
        GetDat(str_test);

        return Json(new { success = true, ViewBag.str_display });
    }
```

HTML -

```
<div id='#nav_div'>@ViewBag.str_display</div>
```

Could someone please help me how ViewBag or Div will show the updated data.

Thanks

Comment: <div id='nav_div'>@ViewBag.str_display</div>

Comment: Just to add a good practice, You must be setting str_display value inside GetDat() method. Why don't you return the value from GetDat() and use it instead. ViewBag is better to be used on View side and not to pass values on server side

Comment: @KD, thanks, I will try to follow your advise

Comment: `ViewBag` is only a thing server-side. To update the value via setting `ViewBag` again, you would have to re-render the whole page. Once you're client-side (i.e. using JavaScript/AJAX), all that exists is the DOM. As a result, if you want to change some value on the page client-side, you must select the applicable element from the DOM and then modify its innerHTML.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, thanks chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try following. change your return statement as follows

```
public JsonResult ddl_2(string str_test)
{
      GetDat(str_test);

      return Json(new { success = true, display = ViewBag.str_display });
}
```

and change your javascript(jquery) as follows

```
 $.post(url, data1, function (data)
 {
      $('#nav_div').html(data.display);
      alert(JSON.stringify(data.display)); // ALERT showing the updated data
 });
```

and change your HTML to `<div id='nav_div'>@ViewBag.str_display</div>`

Comment: Hi Ahamed, it is working but keeping the old value as well, I mean showing the updated value first than showing the old value

Comment: you mean after a period of time you want set the old value back to the div?

Comment: you mean next to each other then you could use $('#nav_div').prepend(data.display+','); instead of  $('#nav_div').html(data.display);

Comment: Basically what is happening, my data is loading when page loaded. when I am implementing your solution, it is keeping the initial value and adding a new row with the updated value, not removing the old value

Comment: Thanks ahamed, I have changed my from div to table and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Your ID contains a '#' character

```
<div id='nav_div'>@ViewBag.str_display</div>
```